# Why doesn't nth-of-type/nth-child work on nested elements?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I'm trying to change the style of odd divs that are inside a div. For some reason the `nth-of-type(odd)` is affecting all my divs when it's inside another div. Here is my code for both the regular div and the odd divs:

```css
.video-entry-summary {
  width: 214px;
  height: 210px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.video-entry-summary:nth-of-type(odd) {
  width: 214px;
  height: 210px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="post-501" class="post-501 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-moto-dz-films tag-news-sub-2">
  <div class="video-entry-summary">
    video 1
  </div>
</div>

<div id="post-240" class="post-240 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-videos">
  <div class="video-entry-summary">
    video 2
  </div>
</div>

<div id="post-232" class="post-232 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-videos">
  <div class="video-entry-summary">
    video 3
  </div>
</div>

<div id="post-223" class="post-223 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-videos">
  <div class="video-entry-summary">
    video 4
  </div>
</div>
```

For some reason, the `nth-of-type` doesn't work when wrapped inside of my divs, but does work when they aren't wrapped inside in any divs.

**Working version when not wrapped inside div:**

```css
.video-entry-summary {
  width: 214px;
  height: 210px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.video-entry-summary:nth-of-type(odd) {
  width: 214px;
  height: 210px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-entry-summary">
  video 1
</div>

<div class="video-entry-summary">
  video 2
</div>

<div class="video-entry-summary">
  video 3
</div>

<div class="video-entry-summary">
  video 4
</div>
```

​How to make the initial code working the same as the above one?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`:nth-of-type()` is similar to `:nth-child()` in that they must all be from the same parent. If you need those wrapper `div`s, use `:nth-of-type()` on those wrappers instead:

```
div.post:nth-of-type(odd) .video-entry-summary {
    width:214px; 
    height:210px; 
    margin-left:0px;
    float:left;
    position:relative; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    border:1px solid black; 
    background:#ccc; 
}
```

If all the siblings are `.post`, use [`:nth-child()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) instead to prevent confusion with [what `:nth-of-type()` really means](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo):

```
.post:nth-child(odd) .video-entry-summary {
    width:214px; 
    height:210px; 
    margin-left:0px;
    float:left;
    position:relative; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    border:1px solid black; 
    background:#ccc; 
}
```

```css
.video-entry-summary {
  width: 214px;
  height: 210px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.post:nth-child(odd) .video-entry-summary {
  width: 214px;
  height: 210px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="post-501" class="post-501 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-moto-dz-films tag-news-sub-2">
  <div class="video-entry-summary">
    video 1
  </div>
</div>

<div id="post-240" class="post-240 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-videos">
  <div class="video-entry-summary">
    video 2
  </div>
</div>

<div id="post-232" class="post-232 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-videos">
  <div class="video-entry-summary">
    video 3
  </div>
</div>

<div id="post-223" class="post-223 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-videos">
  <div class="video-entry-summary">
    video 4
  </div>
</div>
```