# Changing background-color for second and third div

Tags: css

I would like change background color for the second and third div with the class `.offer-info-wrapper`. Of course I use `:nth-of-type(2)` and `:nth-of-type(3)` to change it but it doesn't work. Where is the problem?

```
<section class="offer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="offer-info-wrapper">
            <div class="offer-info">
                <h3>Promotional Email Goals</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipi scing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipi scing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="offer-image">
            <img src="img/entrepreneur.jpg" alt="Entrepreneur">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="offer-info-wrapper">
            <div class="offer-info">
                <h3>Promotional Email Goals</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipi scing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna volutpat.</p>
                <a href="#" class="button">View more</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="offer-image">
            <img src="img/home-office.jpg" alt="Home-office">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="offer-info-wrapper">
            <div class="offer-info">
                <h3>Thinking Ahead</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipi scing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna volutpat.</p>
                <a href="#" class="button">View more</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="offer-image">
            <img src="img/write.jpg" alt="Write">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.offer-info-wrapper:nth-of-type(2),
.offer-info-wrapper:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-color: #41b1b2;
```

}

Comment: they are not under the same parent so every one of .offer-info-wrapper element is the first and the last child of its parent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query won't work because there is only one *type* of `.offer-info-wrapper` per `.row`. Instead, use the `:nth-child` of the `.row` items to access the 2nd and 3rd `.offer-info-wrapper` occurrences.

```css
.row:nth-child(2) .offer-info-wrapper,
.row:nth-child(3) .offer-info-wrapper {
  background-color: #41b1b2;  
}
```

**Demo**

```css
.row:nth-child(2) .offer-info-wrapper,
.row:nth-child(3) .offer-info-wrapper {
  background-color: #41b1b2;
}
```

```html
<section class="offer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="offer-info-wrapper">
      <div class="offer-info">
        <h3>Promotional Email Goals</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipi scing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipi scing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="offer-image">
      <img src="img/entrepreneur.jpg" alt="Entrepreneur">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="offer-info-wrapper">
      <div class="offer-info">
        <h3>Promotional Email Goals</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipi scing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna volutpat.</p>
        <a href="#" class="button">View more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="offer-image">
      <img src="img/home-office.jpg" alt="Home-office">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="offer-info-wrapper">
      <div class="offer-info">
        <h3>Thinking Ahead</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipi scing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna volutpat.</p>
        <a href="#" class="button">View more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="offer-image">
      <img src="img/write.jpg" alt="Write">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8q7xz43y/)

Answer (score 1):

It's the row class you want to focus on. Here's how I would do it so that you can have more .offer-info-wrapper classes and not have to manually apply styles to each one:

```css
.offer-info-wrapper {
    background-color: #41b1b2;
    }
.row:first-child .offer-info-wrapper {
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<section class="offer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="offer-info-wrapper">
            <div class="offer-info">
                <h3>Promotional Email Goals</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipi scing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipi scing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="offer-image">
            <img src="img/entrepreneur.jpg" alt="Entrepreneur">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="offer-info-wrapper">
            <div class="offer-info">
                <h3>Promotional Email Goals</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipi scing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna volutpat.</p>
                <a href="#" class="button">View more</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="offer-image">
            <img src="img/home-office.jpg" alt="Home-office">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="offer-info-wrapper">
            <div class="offer-info">
                <h3>Thinking Ahead</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipi scing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna volutpat.</p>
                <a href="#" class="button">View more</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="offer-image">
            <img src="img/write.jpg" alt="Write">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

:nth-of-type() selector matches every element that is the nth child, of a particular type, of its parent.

Use :nth-child for the row divs instead

```
.row:nth-child(2) .offer-info-wrapper,
.row:nth-child(3) .offer-info-wrapper{
    background-color: #41b1b2;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uncyrvwe/)

Answer (score 0):

Elements you want to modify with the `:nth-of-type()` selector must all be from the same parent.
In your example, each `.offer-info-wrapper` has a `.row` parent, so it won't work.

As stated in the above answer, you need to use the selector on the `.row` items.

This question can be also helpful.

[Why doesn't nth-of-type/nth-child work on nested elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694775/why-doesnt-nth-of-type-nth-child-work-on-nested-elements)